# Display textbox in extjs grid view

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I want to display all textboxes on rendering of grid . But the textbox only shows when you click on that area. Is it possible to display all my textboxes in a grid without any button click ? Below is my code

```
{
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                hideTrigger: true,
                maxValue: 24,
                minValue: 0,
                style: w_textFieldCls,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                disabled: me.readOnly,
                isEditable:true

};
```

Comment: can you put your efforts here [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)?

Answer (score 1):

It was possible. Check this example - http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Plugins/EditableGrid/

But I don't think it is possible now. But here is a good solution for you. Paste it to fiddle(https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) to see the result.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['name']
});

store.add([{'name': 'User 1'}, {'name': 'User 2'}]);

var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }
    }],
    plugins: [cellEditing]
});
```

If you have 1 field to edit, property grid will work much better.

Comment: On editing this text field is dirty indicator shown automatically ? I am not able to get the dirty indicator after field is changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember the details now